Proving a pattern for a system of equations of size N
I've got a system of equations of size N. Here's its definition:
Definition
Let N be an integer $\geq 2$. For N, this system has N equations and N variables. I'll define the variables as $a_0, a_1, a_2, ... a_{N-1}$. These variables are given by:
$$
  a_k =
\begin{cases}
a_{1} + 1,  & \text{for $k=0$} \\
\frac{1}{2}a_{k-1}+\frac{1}{2}a_{k+1}+1, & \text{for $0 > k > N-1$} \\
\frac{1}{2}a_{N-2}+1, & \text{for $k=N-1$}
\end{cases}
$$
Question
I've found, by trial, that $a_0$ is always equal to $N^2$. In fact, it seems that $a_k$ is quadratically distributed; $a_k=-k^2+N^2$ has held true for every case I've tried (which I found via a regression calculator).
I need to prove that $a_0=N^2$, given that the system above is true. It would be fun to also prove $a_k=-k^2+N^2$, but it's not necessary. I don't need someone to entirely work the proof, but I could really use some guidance in the right direction. Nothing I've tried so far has worked.
Example Cases
For clarity, I'll shows a few cases. The base case is $N=2$, which looks like this:
$$
a_0=a_1+1 \\
a_1 = \frac{1}{2}a_0+1
$$
Solving the system, we get $a_0=4, a_1=3$.

Next, N=3:
$$
a_0 = a_1+1 \\
a_1 = \frac{1}{2}a_0+\frac{1}{2}a_2+1 \\
a_2 = \frac{1}{2}a_2+1
$$
Solving the system gives $a_0=9, a_1=8, a_2=5$.

Finally, I'll show a larger case - let's say $N=10$. With an $N$ of $10$, we'll have $10$ variables:
$$
a_0 = a_1+1 \\
a_1 = \frac{1}{2}a_0+\frac{1}{2}a_2+1 \\
a_2 = \frac{1}{2}a_1+\frac{1}{2}a_3+1 \\
a_3 = \frac{1}{2}a_2+\frac{1}{2}a_4+1 \\
a_4 = \frac{1}{2}a_3+\frac{1}{2}a_5+1 \\
a_5 = \frac{1}{2}a_4+\frac{1}{2}a_6+1 \\
a_6 = \frac{1}{2}a_5+\frac{1}{2}a_7+1 \\
a_7 = \frac{1}{2}a_6+\frac{1}{2}a_8+1 \\
a_8 = \frac{1}{2}a_7+\frac{1}{2}a_9+1 \\
a_9 = \frac{1}{2}a_8+1
$$
Solving this system (via an augmented matrix) gives $a_0=100, a_1=99, a_2=96, a_3=91, a_4=84, a_5=75, a_6=64, a_7=51, a_8=36, a_9=19$. Hopefully, the system's definition and the pattern $a_0=N^2$ make sense by now.
Any ideas on proving $a_0=N^2$?

Here's a suggestion:
It appears, from your initial solutions:
4 3
9  8  5

and your own $n = 100$ case, whose solution looks like
100 99 96 91 84 75 64 51 36 19

that the solution has the general form, reading from right to left, of $n^2, n^2 - 1, n^2-4, n^2 - 9, ...$, i.e., that $a_k = n^2 - k^2$.
Replacing that in each term of your defining equations, we get
$$
n^2 - k^2 =
\begin{cases}
(n^2 - 1^2) + 1,  & \text{for $k=0$} \\
\frac{1}{2}(n^2 - (k-1)^2)+\frac{1}{2}(n^2 - (k+1)^2)+1, & \text{for $0 > k > N-1$} \\
\frac{1}{2}(n^2 - (n-2)^2)+1, & \text{for $k=N-1$}
\end{cases}
$$
Simplifying row by row, this gets us
n^2 - k^2 =
\begin{cases}
n^2 ,  & \text{for $k=0$} \\
\frac{1}{2}(n^2 - (k^2 - 2k +1)) +\frac{1}{2}(n^2 - (k^2 + 2k + 1))+1 = \\ 
\frac{1}{2}(n^2 - k^2 + 2k - 1) +\frac{1}{2}(n^2 - k^2 - 2k - 1))+1 = \\ 
\frac{1}{2}(2n^2 - 2k^2  - 2) +1 = \\
(n^2 - k^2)& \text{for $0 > k > N-1$} \\
\frac{1}{2}(n^2 - (n-2)^2)+1 = \\ 
\frac{1}{2}(n^2 - (n^2 - 4n + 4))+1 = \\ 
\frac{1}{2}(n^2 - n^2 + 4n - 4))+1 = \\ 
(2n - 2))+1 = \\ 
(2n - 1)
& \text{for $k=N-1$}
\end{cases}
$$
In all but the last case, this is clearly just $n^2 - k^2$, i.e., we've shown that sequences satisfying the $n^2 - k^2$ pattern also solve your recurrence. For the last, we need only check that
$$
n^2 - (n-1)^2 = 2n - 1
$$
which I leave to you.

What a fascinating way to prove N^2+k^2! Is there a name for this style of proof?

"Substitution"? If you want to show that $x = 3, y = 2$ is a solution to \begin{align} 0 &= 2x - 3y \ 1 &= x - y \end{align}, then simply plugging in the values and showing both equations become true is equivalent to what I did. I didn't show that this was the ONLY solution, but given that we can solve by backsubstitution, it's clear that there's at most one.
